# change operator for a specific function sympy

Tags: sympy

so I would like to create a function that can gives the parity of an operator (the parity liked to the symmetry of mu)

For example :
I have the operator `f(zeta,mu)=rho(zeta,mu)*Derivative(Ylm(mu,phi),mu)` where rho the density is even and the derivative along mu is odd, Ylm is a spherical harmonic.

I apply the function parity :
`parity(f)=odd * parity (Ylm(zeta,mu))`

So the function parity is working like that:

```
parity(a+b) returns odd if parity(a)=parity(b)=odd
parity(a+b) returns even if parity(a)=parity(b)=even
parity(a+b) returns no_parity if parity(a)=even,  parity(b)=odd or the contrary

parity(a*b)=parity(a)*parity(b)
even*odd=odd
odd*odd=even
even*even=even 

parity(Derivative(a,mu))=odd*parity(a)
```

and we have a dictionary of a certain number of basic functions for exemple:

`dic={rho(zeta,mu):even, Ylm(mu,phi): parity(Ylm(mu,phi))}`

Thank you for helping